# How to obtain the closed form solution to this nonlinear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem

I have the following simple but nonlinear ODE system problem below:

$$\left\{
\begin{align}
 &f'(t)=a\cdot (1-f(t)-g(t))^{13/10}\tag{1}\\
 &g'(t)=b \cdot f(t) \tag{2}\\
&f(0)=0,\quad g(0)=0,\quad a,b\in \mathbb{R},t\in[0,1000]\\
\end{align}
\right.$$

I tried to solve it in Maple, the solver gives result without initial or boundary conditions but does not solve it with ibcs.

How to obtain the exact solution with IBCs?

Comment: Yes,thank you! let me update it!

Comment: Sure about your system? For example, if $a=b=1$, the solution $(f(t),g(t))$ is only defined for $t_*<t<t^*$ for some finite $t_*<0<t^*$. What if $t^*<1000$?